# Rounding leading decimal points to 2 not saving when using toFixed

Tags: javascript, floating-point, tofixed

I am trying to convert a value like 20.0123 to 20.01 by using toFixed(2). For some reason it does convert correctly but going along my code it goes back to not a fixed value.

```
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
  let change=(cash-price).toFixed(2);
  console.log(change);   
  let changeArr = [];
  let count=0;
  if(change>=20){
    while(change>=20&&cid[7][1]>0){
      console.log(change);
      change-=20;cid[7][1]-=20;count++;
    }
    changeArr.push(['TWENTY',20*count]);
    count=0;
  }
...
}

checkCashRegister(3.26, 100, ...);
```

My output would end up as

```
96.74
96.74
76.74
56.739999999999995
```

Not sure why it changes back to not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

When you use toFixed it returns a string. When you do a minus on it the type returns to a number:

```js
let num_a = 76.7443434.toFixed(2);

console.log(num_a, typeof num_a);

let num_b = num_a - 20;

console.log(num_b, typeof num_b);
```

Note: if you use plus instead of minus it will concatenate to the string (and keep the type string) rather than add to the number.

There are javascript libraries like [decimal.js](https://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/) that allow you to avoid these issues (at the cost of some slightly more involved code).

Another way to consider might be to work in pence.